# Why can't I initialize a board with chess pieces here?

Tags: rust, chess

I'm trying to create a chess library from a template. I'm trying to initialize a chess board as a 2d-array containing chess pieces as a struct.

I get a syntax error on this line:

```
board:[0][0] = white_pawn_1: Piece { colour: 0, role: 0 },
```

This is how the code looks before that:

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum GameState {
    InProgress,
    Check,
    GameOver,
    CheckMate
}

/* IMPORTANT:
 * - Document well!
 * - Write well structured and clean code!
 * - Read the Rust documentation, ask questions if you get stuck!
 */
struct Piece {
    colour: u8,
    role: u8
} 

impl Piece {
    fn description (&self) {
        print!("Colour: {}, ", self.colour);
        println!("Role: {}", self.role);
    }

    fn new(colour: u8, role: u8) -> Piece {
        Piece {colour: colour, role: role}
    }
}


pub struct Game {
    /* save board, active colour, ... */
    state: GameState,
    board: [Option<Piece>; 8 * 8],

    white_pawn_1: Piece,
    white_pawn_2: Piece,
    white_pawn_3: Piece,
    white_pawn_4: Piece,
    white_rook: Piece,
    white_knight: Piece,
    white_bishop: Piece,
    white_queen: Piece,
    white_king: Piece,

    black_pawn_1: Piece,
    black_pawn_2: Piece,
    black_pawn_3: Piece,
    black_pawn_4: Piece,
    black_rook: Piece,
    black_knight: Piece,
    black_bishop: Piece,
    black_queen: Piece,
    black_king: Piece
 

}

impl Game {
    /// Initialises a new board with pieces.
    pub fn new() -> Game {
        Game {
            /* initialise board, set active colour to white, ... */
            state: GameState::InProgress,
          
            white_pawn_1: Piece { colour: 0, role: 0 },
            white_pawn_2: Piece { colour: 0, role: 0 },
            white_pawn_3: Piece { colour: 0, role: 0 },
            white_pawn_4: Piece { colour: 0, role: 0 },
            white_rook: Piece { colour: 0, role: 1 },
            white_knight: Piece { colour: 0, role: 2 },
            white_bishop: Piece { colour: 0, role: 3 },
            white_queen: Piece { colour: 0, role: 4 },
            white_king: Piece { colour: 0, role: 5 },

            black_pawn_1: Piece { colour: 1, role: 0 },
            black_pawn_2: Piece { colour: 1, role: 0 },
            black_pawn_3: Piece { colour: 1, role: 0 },
            black_pawn_4: Piece { colour: 1, role: 0 },
            black_rook: Piece { colour: 1, role: 1 },
            black_knight: Piece { colour: 1, role: 2 },
            black_bishop: Piece { colour: 1, role: 3 },
            black_queen: Piece { colour: 1, role: 4 },
            black_king: Piece { colour: 1, role: 5 },
                    
            board:[0][0] = white_pawn_1: Piece { colour: 0, role: 0 },
            
        
        }
    }
```

Any ideas how i can correct the syntax?

Comment: What is that even supposed to do? `board` is a one dimensional array. You'll need to initialize it with an [array literal](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html)

Comment: That is not valid Rust syntax, so I'd strongly suggest you keep [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) on hand when figuring things out.

Comment: The Rust way of expressing this is probably to have a `Player` or `Color` enum for `White` vs. `Black` and a `Piece` struct which is like `struct Piece(PieceType, Color)`. This could even be an enum like `enum Piece { Black(PieceType), White(PieceType), None }`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize it with

```
board: [None; 64],
```

Or create a builder pattern for it to assign values at board positions.